# Open app with URL Scheme from Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, url

I'm trying to open my iOS app from my Facebook page throught a custom URL Scheme.
I tried to add a custom URL Scheme in my app (and if I type it in Safari my app opens), I tried to add Facebook SDK in my app, configuring info.plist with all parameters like app ID and FacebookUrlScheme, but my app does not open in any case.
I don't have any other ideas and I didn't find any guide or tutorial for this.